# how to connect two database on the different host at the same time using php and mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, database-connection

```
$connection1 = mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password);
$db1 = mysql_select_db($dbname,$connection1);

some html and php code here

$connection2 = mysql_connect($servername1,$username1,$password1);    
$db2 = mysql_select_db($dbname1,$connection2);
```

**Error:**

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user '*****'@'***.com' (using password: YES) in /home/

Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /home/

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user '******'@'********' (using password: NO) in /home/

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/
```

I get this error when i want to fetch something or try to connect

Comment: Pretty sure this error sums up the entire problem you have: `Access denied for user '******'@'********'`

Comment: and stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Use MySQLi / PDO instead.

Comment: are you able to connect one of them alone!, this seems more of an access issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to add IP address from your hosting cpanel at option Remove MySQL to allow remote access.